# Select into statement

Tags: select-into

Is it possible to use "select into" statement when we are  joining different tables which have 1 or more same column names?
Eg: Table1 has column name as description and Table2 has column name as description 
and I want both these columns data in my new table

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `select into` is used to store scalar results into variables inside a procedural language. Not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible on most database systems, but you can't have 2 columns with the same name -- so you would have to rename one of them, e.g.

```
Select
a.Field1,
a.Field2,
b.Field2 as NewFieldName,  -- using an alias
b.Field3
INTO...
```

Notice in this example, both table 'a' and 'b' have a column Field2.